# How to decide which element is being clicked in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have more similar elements in HTML which are being added continously with PHP. my question is the following:

With jQuery, I would like to add a click event to each of these `<div>` elements. When any of them is being clicked it should display it's content. The problem is that I guess I need to use classes to specify which elements can be clickable. But in this case the application will not be able to decide which specific element is being clicked, right?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<div class="test">5</div>
```

**jQuery try:**

```
$("test").on("click", function()
{
    var data = ???
    alert(data);
});
```

**UPDATE - QUESTION 2:**

What happens if I'm placing `<a>` tags between those divs, and I want to get their `href` value when the DIV is being clicked?

I always get an error when I try that with `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` refers to the element triggering the event. Note that it is a regular js element, so you'll need to convert it to a jQuery object before you can use jQuery functions: `$(this)`

```
$(".test").on("click", function()
{
    var data = $(this).text();
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you it is working as expected. And what happens if I'm using `<a>` tags within those divs, and I would like to get their HREF value, when the div is being clicked? Because I can't seem to make that work with `this`.

Comment: Try this: `var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
    alert(href);`

Comment: Ah, thank you, it is working now very well. Thanks for all the help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$(".test").on("click", function(event)
{
    var data = $(event.target);
    alert(data.text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this variable contains the reference of current item

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".test").click(function(event) {

    var data = $(this).text();
    alert(data);
        });
    })
```

;

Answer (score 0):

The class selector in jquery is $(".ClassName") and to access the value, use $(this) as such:

```
$(".test").on("click", function(){
    var data = $(this).text();
    alert(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` inside the function which mean clicked div

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LnpLB/1/)

```
$(".test").on("click", function () {
     alert($(this).html());
});
```